# Message displays before clicking on the submit button

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am currently in the process of following a tutorial, the instructor in question has a form, when he clicks on the "submit" button without having entered any information, a message "you must complete all fields" is displayed. The problem is with me: I wrote the same code as him but the message appears at the start of the page loading, i.e. without even clicking on the submit button.

By the way, he said that we'll use `$_SESSION["message"]=null;` to not display that message when we load the form page.

**Here is the session.php code**

```
<?php

session_start();
function Message(){
    if(isset($_SESSION["message"]))
    {
        $Output="<div class=\"message\">";
        $Output .= htmlentities($_SESSION["message"]);
        $Output .="</div>";
        $_SESSION["message"]=null;
        return $Output;
    }
}
?>
```

**And the user_registration.php code:**

`

```
  <?php require("include/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("include/database.php"); ?>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  $Username=mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection,$_POST["Username"]);
  $Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection,$_POST["Email"]);
  $Password=mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection,$_POST["Password"]);
  $ConfirmPassword=mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection,$_POST["ConfirmPassword"]);

}
if(empty($Username)&&empty($Email)&&empty($Password)&&empty($ConfirmPassword)){
  $_SESSION["message"]="All Fields must be filled out";

  
}else if($Password!==$ConfirmPassword){
  $_SESSION["message"]="Both passwords must be the same";

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE>

<html>
<head>
<title>
Register Now
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="include/Styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div><?php echo Message(); ?></div>
  
<div id="centerpage">
    <form action="./user_registration.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <span class="FieldInfo">Username:</span><br><input type="text" name="Username" value=""><br>
    <span class="FieldInfo">Email:</span><br><input type="email" name="Email" value=""><br>
    <span class="FieldInfo">Password:</span><br><input type="password" name="Password" value=""><br>
    <span class="FieldInfo">Confirme Password:</span><br><input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" value=""><br>
    <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: I think it has to do with your 'user_registration.php code'. I'm not sure, but I think the first } is in the wrong place. Because of that, this code `if(empty($Username)&&empty($Email)&&empty($Password)&&empty($ConfirmPassword)){
 $_SESSION["message"]="All Fields must be filled out";` stands on it's own and always returns `true`. So you get the message about the empty fields right away, because they are all empty.

Comment: The session already exists. Destroy it with session_destroy when you know its already been displayed

Comment: BTW, you should be combining all the `empty()` checks with `||`, not `&&`, so you complain if any field is empty. Your code only complains if *all* the fields are empty.

Comment: Why do you use `mysqli_real_escape_string`? Remove them

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 0):

You must check the empty input inside the if (isset($_POST['submit'] )) statement. So you have to change it in

```
If(isset($_POST[“submit”])){
$Username=mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection,$_POST[“Username”]);
$Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection,$_POST[“Email”]);
$Password=mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection,$_POST[“Password”]);
$ConfirmPassword=mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection,$_POST[“ConfirmPassword”]); 
If(empty($Username)&&empty($Email)&&empty($Password)&&empty($ConfirmPassword)){
 $_SESSION[“message”]=”All Fields must be filled out”;
 }else if($Password!==$ConfirmPassword){
 $_SESSION[“message”]=”Both passwords must be the same”;
 }
 }
```